# RSS feeds are truncated but want them to have full content

Tags: rss, feed, content-tag

I've customized the rss feed for scottwclifton.com here: feeds.feedburner.com/scottclifton

Where is the  tag. I need the full content to display on the RSS feeds somewhere so I can use them in my mailings but it looks like there is only a description for each blog. Help? I'm using Genesis Theme and haven't set up anything that I know of out of the ordinary.

Comment: First, you probably need to fix your "original" feed and not the feedburner feed... Care to share the link to the original feed?

Comment: http://www.scottwclifton.com/feed/

Comment: Scoot, this feed is truncated... you can't expect feedburner to have the full content if your original feed has truncated entries...

Comment: I know it's truncated...how do I get it untruncated! That's the point! How?

Answer (score 0):

The [original feed](http://www.scottwclifton.com/feed/) is truncated, which means that if you want the feedburner feed to have the full content, you need to original feed to have the full content.

The original feed seems to be a wordpress feed. In your blog's settings, check the *reading* section and make sure the "Full Text" radio button is enabled by "For each article in a feed, show".